# Changing initial value on input subfile with SFLINZ keyword

Tags: ibm-midrange

I need to change the default value that gets loaded on the screen when we initialize a input subfile with SFLINZ keyword.

At present all character fields are by default loaded with *Blank values. The requirement is to change to this to a non-blank value for one of the fields defined in the subfile record.

Can anyone please help on how we can go ahead in achieving the same.

Thanks & Regards,
Vikash Shaw

Answer (score 1):

The documentation at [the knowledgecenter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzakc/rzakcmstdfsflnz.htm) says:

> The fields in each subfile record are initialized to blanks for character type fields, to nulls for floating-point type fields, to zeros for other numeric type fields, or to the constant value specified on input-only fields if the DFT keyword is specified.

So as long as the field you want to set a default for is input only, you can initialize it to whatever constant you want by using the `DFT` keyword. Otherwise you will have to loop through and update all the records with the appropriate value before you display it.